# Isbell duality between $\text{Set}$ and $\text{Set}^{\text{op}}$.

Tags: category-theory

Provided a small category $G$, the [Isbell duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+duality) establishes an adjunction:

$$\text{Set}^{G^{\text{op}}}  \leftrightarrows (\text{Set}^{G})^{\text{op}}.  $$

Both maps can be computed as Kan extensions. Call $y : G \to \text{Set}^{G^{\text{op}}}  $ and $y^{t}: G \to (\text{Set}^{G})^{\text{op}} $ the Yoneda embeddings, then one can obtain the two adjoints as $\text{Lan}_y y^t$ and  $\text{Lan}_{y^t} y.$

I am interested in a special computation of these maps. Choose $G$ to be the terminal category, so that we are looking at the adjunction:

$$\text{Set} \leftrightarrows  \text{Set}^{\text{op}} .$$

Is there an explicit presentation of these two adjoint functors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every set is a coproduct of points, and the left adjoint sends the point to itself, so it sends any set to a product of points, that is, it's constant. Similarly, or by adjunction, the right adjoint is constant. There's an error in your treatment: the opposite category of sets is the free completion of a point under limits, and so the right adjoint must be defined by *right* Kan extension along $y^t$.

Comment: Thus you claim that both functors are the constant functor? I got the same result.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Yep.

Comment: Don't you think that is very strange that the functor is so uninteresting?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I can't speak for Kevin Carlson, but no it doesn't seem strange at all. When $G=\mathbf 1$ then both $y$ and $y^t$ are the constantly terminal object (of $\mathbf{Set}$) functor. It doesn't seem strange at all that the Kan extension of a trivial functor along another trivial functor is trivial. Being a bit cavalier about size issues, $y^t$ is an initial object so you'd expect $\text{Lan}_J y^t$ to be the initial object for any $J$ of the appropriate type. Similarly, for the right Kan extension.

Comment: I agree with Derek. Cocontinuous functors out of sets are boring.